# What condition makes a symmetric matrix similar to itself under arbitary orthogonal matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**The question**:

All matrices involved are real. If $Q$ is arbitary orthogonal ($Q^TQ = I$) matrix and $A$ is some symmetric matrix, what are the iff conditions required for $A = Q^TAQ$ to be ture?

**My thoughts**:

I know that not all $A$'s are valid. For example, let
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 1 \\ 
1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and
$$
Q = \begin{bmatrix} 
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \\ 
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
then
$$
Q^TAQ = \begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 \\ 
0 & -1 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which is not equal to $A$.

Also, it is easy to verify that it holds when $A = \lambda I$ where $\lambda$ is some contant.

But what else conditions are needed?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It means that $Q$ lies in the orthogonal group defined by the quadratic form associated to $A$ which is a condition I'm unsure you can simplify. Maybe use the fact that $A$ and $Q$ commute and thus that $Q$ stabilises the eigen spaces of $A$ ?

Comment: We show that $A$ has exactly one eigenvalue. If not, we have $A\alpha=\lambda_1\alpha,A\beta=\lambda_2\beta.$ Then $\alpha+\beta$ isn't the eigenvector of $A.$

Comment: In your example iwe have $A^2=I.$ Hence for $A=Q$ we get $A=Q^TAQ=A^3=A.$